# Use non monoBehaviour class in unity

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm going through a bug or at least something i don't really get.

I'm trying to use sqlite database in my unity project.

Here is the error i get:

[image]

The DatabaseManager class is a MonoBehaviour class.

Here is what it looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;

void Awake() 
{
    string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "game.db");
    var dbTemplatePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "default.db");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath)) {
        // game database does not exists, copy default db as template
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            // Must use WWW for streaming asset
            WWW reader = new WWW(dbTemplatePath);
            while ( !reader.isDone) {}
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dbPath, reader.bytes);
        } else {
            System.IO.File.Copy(dbTemplatePath, dbPath, true);
        }       
    }
    sqlDB = new SqliteDatabase(dbPath);
}
}
```

The thing is that if i got it right, the fact that i put my scripts under the assets folder should be enough for them to work together and recognize classes in other files. Now the problem is simple i my DatabaseManager class does not recognize the SqliteDatabase class which is implemented in SqliteDatabase.cs

Have someone had this issue or did i miss something on how to reference a non MonoBehaviour script in a MonoBehaviour one ?

EDIT:

I used this tutorial : [Here](http://bravenewmethod.com/2015/04/11/quickstart-sqlite-unity/)

Thanks !

Comment: "DatabaseManager class does not recognize the SqliteDatabase class which is implemented in SqliteDatabase.cs", what is the error message? The simplest attempt might be change .net 2.0 to 3.5 in play setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having a minor capitalization typo in your code.

Replace `SQLiteDatabase sqlDB` with `SqliteDatabase sqlDB`.

Comment: Please explain your answer so that others find it useful. Thanks

Comment: Of course. The bold letters in S**QL**iteDatabase are capitalised when they should not be.